# How to limit number of attempts someone has to provide username/password credentials for a webpage with htpasswd?

Tags: apache-2.2

I've enabled htpasswd on a webpage.  Is there a way I can limit the number of attempts a user has to enter the correct username/pass credentials before they have to do a hard refresh of the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with basic authentication, you'll need to go to a different authentication module in order to do it.  I was just reading up on mod_auth_pamacea which allows you to use the PAM libraries and all of their goodness with `.htpasswd`.  You could setup a separate service for your http authentication and then use pam_tally.so to limit the number of login attempts.  Here are a couple of links for your reading pleasure:

[The Linux-PAM System Administrators' Guide](http://debian.securedservers.com/kernel/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html)

[mod_auth_pamacea Documentation](http://www.columbia.edu/acis/dev/projects/mod_auth_pamacea/doc.shtml)

I'm sure there are other auth modules that will allow the same functionality, to me this is the closest you'll come to `mod_auth_basic`.